# How do I sort the same index of a tuple by Numerically (descending) and Alphabetically? [Python]

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I have been set a task to sort a given list of tuples through a parameter of a function like this. I have to get the function to operate with only two lines of code. 
The sort order is as such:
1) Grade
2) Surname
3) Forename

So for example one doctest would be:

```
sortStudents([('Tim Smith', 54), ('Anna Smith', 88), ('Barry Thomas', 88)])
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def sortStudents(a):
    return (sorted(a, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0].split()[1], x[0].split()[0])))
```

And I have got these tests to work. However the last doctest I can't get to pass is one with Alphabetical grades rather than numerical ones. And as I am sorting in descending numerical values (by index) it would reverse the alphabetical sort at the same time. An example of the doctest would be:

```
sortStudents([('Tim Jones', 'C'), ('Anna Smith', 'B'), ('Barry Thomas', 'A')])
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know for sure that the grade is exactly one letter?

Comment: In this task yes.

Comment: @MorganThrapp you're misunderstanding it still, the post you're referring to talks about different indexes, I am talking about the same index of the tuple, but different parameter type.

Comment: I'm assuming this is for homework, because having a data structure with a variable data type like that is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the grade *type* (string or integer) to determine how the sorting should be done:

```
def sortStudents(a):
    return sorted(a, key=lambda x: [-x[1] if isinstance(x[1], int) else x[1]] 
                                   + x[0].split()[::-1])
```

You may also the name split once, and reverse the list, instead of splitting twice.

Comment: [Answered] Thanks so much, I thought it was something along the lines of a type problem!

Comment: Minor caution, this will throw an exception on Python 3 if the list contains mixed types for the grades since in 3 strings and ints aren't comparable. In Python 2 it will group sort all numeric grades for a name below all string grades for that name. Which may be the desired behavior.

Answer (score -2):

You could try:

```
def sortStudents(a):
    return (sorted(a, key=lambda x: (-int(str(x[1]).replace("A","90").replace("B","80").replace("C","70")), x[0].split()[1], x[0].split()[0])))
```

It seems like a bit of a silly exercise, but this does what you need it to do, I think.

```
>>> a = [('Tim Smith', 54), ('Anna Smith', 88), ('Barry Thomas', 88)]
>>> b=[('Tim Jones', 'C'), ('Anna Smith', 'B'), ('Barry Thomas', 'A')]
>>> sortStudents(a)
[('Anna Smith', 88), ('Barry Thomas', 88), ('Tim Smith', 54)]
>>> sortStudents(b)
[('Barry Thomas', 'A'), ('Anna Smith', 'B'), ('Tim Jones', 'C')]
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain well, the two line should include both the definition and body. So exactly one line of code for the function body itself.

Comment: This is very unidiomatic. Why are you using `try/except` for this? And specifically a catch all `except`.

Comment: @MorganThrapp, I agree, but if you ask a silly question you should expect a silly answer!